# Разъяснить насчёт чего-то / разъяснить что-то

Tags: стилистика

Возможно ли употребление выражения "разъясните мне насчёт [чего-либо]"? Или разъяснять можно только что-то?

Answer (score 2):

**1) Давайте грамотно пользоваться грамотной русской речью!**

**2) Я считаю неверным следующее высказывание**: "...я не вижу другого выхода из положения, разве что разводить всякие придаточные, а язык стремится к экономии средств... Ведь не срок же разъяснить? А значит, надо громоздить конструкцию: "разъяснить, в какие сроки следует..."Канцеляризм, сберегающий наше время; ведь "разъяснения касательно" вполне нормативно".

**3) Варианты предлагаемых нормативных предложений:**

Дать разъяснения по поводу учебников, срока/относительно учебников, срока...

Но нельзя "разъяснить" учебники и сроки.

**4) Ответы на очень многие вопросы нужно искать в толковых словарях**

**<По поводу кого-чего. в зн. предлога.** 1. Относительно кого-, чего-л. Решение по поводу премьерного фильма. Высказаться по поводу результатов голосования.

**РАЗЪЯСНИТЬ,**  что или с придат. дополнит. (кому). Сделать ясным, понятным, объяснив что-л. Р. программу действий.  Р., в чём дело.

**РАЗЪЯСНЕНИЕ,** - 1. к Разъяснить - разъяснять и Разъясниться - разъясняться. Ждать разъяснения. Действовать методом разъяснения и убеждения. 2. То, что разъясняет что-л. Получить р. Давать разъяснения. Обратиться за разъяснениями.

Comment: >> *Давайте грамотно пользоваться грамотной русской речью!* А ведь это перл )))

Comment: Ну да, а что вас не устраивает? Экономика должна быть экономной. А фразу следует понимать так. Здесь говорилось, что язык стремится к экономии средств и хотели ему в этом помочь. А он уже достиг определенного предела совершенства и в помощи не нуждается. Надо просто грамотно пользоваться теми грамматическими конструкциями, которые уже есть в наличии.

Comment: Niemand, а Вы не заметили, что во всём, что не скопипащено, перл на перле сидит и им же погоняет? )))

Comment: Скопипастить - от слов Copy (Копировать) и Paste(Вставить) . Этого слова нет в словаре, но в Интернете можно найти его значение, например: скопипастить - значит "содрать"(своровать) откуда-то текст, картинки или еще чего-нибудь и выдать за свое.  Вы  это имели в виду, уважаемая Galina Avanesova,  я правильно Вас поняла?  Вы хотите сказать, что все мои ответы - это или скопированный где-то материал, или "перлы", то есть нечто нелепое, смешное, бессмысленное. Вы именно это хотели сказать?

Comment: Вера, кто решил, что "он уже достиг определённого предела совершенства и в помощи не нуждается"? Кто это утвердил, где подпись, печать? Ведь опять перл...     Галина, это да, частенько так и есть. ))

Comment: Niemand, очень жаль, но писателем Вам никогда не быть, у Вас начисто отсутствует художественное мышление, а все слова для Вас исключительно однозначные и используются только в прямом смысле, остальная же  их семантика (переносная)  - это  "перлы".  Ну право же, невозможно каждую фразу переводить на понятный Вам язык, да еще с подписью и печатью. Есть такие художественные приемы, как ирония и гротеск, но Вам они совершенно недоступны.

Comment: Поэтому давайте не будем "грамотно пользоваться грамотной русской речью",  но узаконим  речь неграмотную, но простую  и будем  "разъяснять насчет срока, учебников и т.д. ", как предлагает Galina Avanesova.  И еще давайте на этом форуме обсуждать не вопросы, а отвечающих, желательно в грубо-просторечной форме. И  травить тех, кто  имеет свое собственное мнение, вместо того чтобы обмениваться мнениями и обсуждать сказанное.

Answer (score 1):

Формально - да. Единственное литературное управление *разъяснить что-л*. Предлог *насчёт* - разговорный: касательно, относительно кого-, чего-л.

Но вот в последнем сообщении из скрина:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

я не вижу другого выхода из положения, разве что разводить всякие придаточные, а язык стремится к экономии средств... Ведь не срок же разъяснить? А значит, надо громоздить конструкцию: "разъяснить, в какие сроки следует..."

Канцеляризм, сберегающий наше время; ведь "разъяснения касательно" вполне нормативно, оно и породило форму "разъяснить касательно", ненормативную.

Comment: Галина, в СМИ бывают очень много ошибок.  Употреблять, а тем более приводить примеры предложения с этими предлогами, не правильно.

Comment: Серж, я говорю о двух вещах: с одной стороны, частотность употребления, с другой - подчёркиваю ненормативность "разъяснить касательно".

Comment: А-а, простите, я вас не так понял.

Answer (score 1):

Я нашёл только один [пример](https://books.google.ru/books?id=XpYHAQAAIAAJ&q=%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%8A%D1%8F%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%20%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%87%D1%91%D1%82&dq=%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%8A%D1%8F%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%20%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%87%D1%91%D1%82&hl=ru&sa=X&redir_esc=y) с "разъясните мне насчёт":

> Разъясните мне насчет вашего перевода: вам требуется эссе о кино, или просто эссе, или роман, или всё равно что, лишь бы это было хорошо написано?

Значит, так действительно мало говорят.

Однако, на мой взгляд, говорить с "насчёт" в разговорной речи вполне допустимо. В таком случае правильным будет сказать:

- разъясните мне насчёт чего-то ***конкретного***
- разъясните мне ***ситуацию*** (с чем-то), ***проблему*** (чего-то), ***историю*** (с кем-то, о чём-то или ком-то), ***обстоятельства*** (чего-то) и т. д.

Answer (score 1):

Переходный глагол "разъяснить" во многих ситуациях может использоваться без прямого дополнения (напр. "*Разъясните мне, какой закон я нарушил*"). В ещё большей степени это относится к отглагольному существительному "разъяснение". Именно с существитетельным связывается посредством слова "насчёт" (относительно, касательно и пр.) часть предложения, следующая за *вполне корректным* выражением "**Дайте мне разъяснения насчёт...**". Однако, в выражении "**Разъясните мне насчёт...**" слово "насчёт" повисает в воздухе ("слева" его не с чем связать) и этим подчёркивает отсутствие прямого дополнения при переходном глаголе. В результате, данное выражение производит впечатление разговорного упрощения, если не просторечия.